# How is sampling rate affect the Doppler spectrum? Textbook attached

Tags: frequency-spectrum, sampling, doppler

I am studying FWGN model, in the textbook "MIMO-OFDM wireless communication with MATLAB", it says "When oversampled by a factor of $N_OS$, the bandwidth of Doppler spectrum becomes \begin{equation}BD = 2N_{0S}f_m\end{equation} as shown in Figure 2.8(b)"

My question is why the Doppler spectrum becomes \begin{equation}BD = 2N_{0S}f_m\end{equation} , if we oversample it by the factor of Nos.
[image: Textbook snip]

Comment: sampling rate doesn't affect the observed thing at all. It does affect your observation. However, the page you cite seems to explain that pretty well, so, honestly, not quite sure what you're asking here?

Comment: My question is why the Doppler spectrum becomes 2*Nos*fm, if we oversample it by the factor of Nos.@Marcus Müller

Comment: the text is a bit imprecise there; the Doppler spectrum doesn't change, your observation changes. See (b) in your figure.